# How social media end-to-end encryption really works

Tags: facebook, encryption, social-networking

I was wondering,facebook(for example) has end-to-end encryption of your messages,shouldn't you be able to see that messages only from the pc from you sent those messages.I mean local keys are stored on localy pc,right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook uses signal, see Open Whisper Systems
[TECHNICAL DOCUMENTATION](https://whispersystems.org/docs/).